# How to include External jQuery File in default.aspx?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

How should I create **External jQuery** File and how should I include that
*jQuery file* in to my *default.aspx* file ?

Comment: What do you mean by external jQuery file. Are you adding the path from internet??

Comment: External jQuery File Means ... jquery File that have my own code...

Answer (score 0):

you may create your external js file which includes valid scripting code with the .js extension and you may include it using script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/your_jsfile.js"></script>
```

You may refer from http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/external.shtml

Comment: ok. where should i include the downloaded "JScript.js" in " /your_jsfile.js " or "default.aspx"

Comment: you may place it in your application and then use relative path or if for example I place it on my local at the path C:/myFolder/your_jsfile.js then I will specify the complete path like src="C:/myFolder/your_jsfile.js".

Comment: In src you need to specify the name of the js file along with the path on the server.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

jquery-1.10.1.min.js file is present on external server

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

if present on your own server

```
   <script src="path_to_js/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```